# How do I use message resource?

Tags: twilio

Given a message sid, I want to retrieve the current status of the message. I found this online

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource

`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{Sid}.json`

I put my accountSid and the messsage sid but I get this?

```
{
    "code": 20003,
    "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003",
    "status": 401
}
```

Also is there anyway in nodejs to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can switch the programming language in the tab on the top-right in the resource document that you linked.

[image: Docs]

In there, you find this snippet for Node.js

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages('MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .fetch()
      .then(message => console.log(message.to));
```

PS: The **No credentials provided** error that you see comes from undefined credentials. Have a look [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/requests-to-twilio#credentials) to see where you can find your credentials and how to add them to requests.

Comment: This is exactly what I need thanks! Do you know if there is a way to lookup notify sid and retrieve the message sid of all the bindings ? (I can live without this, but would be nicer)

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry

Comment: Hi, sorry. One more thing, is there a cost attached to using the fetch message API ?

Comment: As of today, no, only sending and receiving text messages costs something.